# Why does nobody makes a new peripherical connector based on ending interrupts signals to processors such as PS/2?

Tags: usb, keyboard, cpu, ps2, interrupts

Most specialists agree that for a mouse and a keyboard the most efficient way to communicate with the processor is based on interrupts (the way it is done in PS/2 ports) rather than polling (the way it is done in USB ports)

However there are more and more keyboards nowadays that do not support PS/2 adapters.

Why does nobody try to make a port that is faster but still based on processor interrupts?

Comment: There is a great answer here for a related (more general) question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3072959/6207268

Comment: So many downvotes. Wow.

Comment: @Argonauts  I knew all the information in that answer. My question was completely different. I know what is the difference very well. i am asking why nobody considered to make a better interrupt-based port.

Comment: You may have known the material in that post but you either disagree or don't understand as it does tell you 'why'

Comment: @Argonauts  I think the reason we are disagreeing here is that you don't actually understand that post not vice-versa.

Answer (score 2):

...because dealing with the `V E R Y   S L O W` signals from mice and keyboards is not a bottleneck for today's processors, so "making it more efficient" gains pretty much nothing in real terms. You have on the one hand a common, widespread, standard that works, and on the other hand mostly mythical improvements from developing a new interface and hoping that anyone will use it.

Consider how much time it takes to poll 100 times a second on a system running 2 GHz. 100 Hz (the polling rate) divided by 2,000,000,000 Hz (the processor clock rate.) A miniscule proportion of the processor time - 1 in twenty million cycles. Not going to speed things up much at all if you stop doing that, but it sure is going to cost a lot to change from USB to something new, and PS/2 ports are pretty obsolete in the other direction.

Many things that mattered when trying to bang out a computer on a 1970's/80's microprocessor don't make a heck of a lot of sense to perpetuate in 2016.

Comment: Polling one time takes much much more than one cycle. And to get the same performance as ps/2 you have to poll more than 1000 times per second.

Comment: Gosh, you must *type really fast* if that's a concern. Make it 2000 times a second and take 10 cycles - you're still looking at 0.001% performance impact on a middle of the road 2 GHz processor. Still not a sensible candidate for (expensive, risky) optimization.

Comment: Who said anything about typing. I am talking about competitive gaming where 10 ms is a LOT. Why do you have to make assumptions without knowing what the subject is about ? You could have asked why do you need fast response time. it is a no-brainer that for typing it does not matter. Gosh.